# Why by exposing uwsgi port from within a container, nginx receives 502 BAD GATEWAY?

Tags: docker, nginx, uwsgi, proxypass

I have built a `Dockerfile` like below:

```
FROM python:2-jessie

ENV DOCKER_MODE=1

EXPOSE 1818

# everything is copied to my_app like uwsgi.ini and app files
COPY . /my_app

WORKDIR /my_app

CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"]
```

It works like a charm:

```
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - uWSGI http bound on 127.0.0.1:1818 fd 4
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:43183 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - Python version: 2.7.14 (default, Oct 10 2017, 02:49:49)  [GCC 4.9.2]
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1e347e0
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - python threads support enabled
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 10 seconds
Sun Oct 29 15:17:34 2017 - mapped 1155328 bytes (1128 KB) for 50 cores
Sun Oct 29 15:17:35 2017 - WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x1e347e0 pid: 1 (default app)
Sun Oct 29 15:17:35 2017 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Sun Oct 29 15:17:35 2017 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
Sun Oct 29 15:17:35 2017 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 9, cores: 50)
Sun Oct 29 15:17:35 2017 - *** Stats server enabled on 127.0.0.1:11818 fd: 12 ***
Sun Oct 29 15:17:35 2017 - spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 10)
```

When I run the docker image and assign a port like `33000`, it is listening on that port:

```
admin@server:~/application$ sudo netstat -nltp | grep 33000
tcp6       0      0 :::33000                :::*                    LISTEN      10922/docker-proxy
```

Nothing seems wrong! Now my nginx proxy pass requests like below on port 80:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:33000;
```

When I send my request to port `80`, I get `502 Bad Gateway Error`. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

UWSGI was bound to `127.0.0.1`, I changed it to `0.0.0.0` on container. and has something like below:

```
http-socket=0.0.0.0:1818
```